# $ is not a function, in my script on front (jQuery load in footer)

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have a problem with my `js` in `Drupal 8`. I want to use `jquery` of *Drupal 8 core*, but I can't because I have this error on chrome :

```
marmite-src\js\_store.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at Object.3 (marmite-src\js\_store.js:26)
    at s (_prelude.js:1)
    at _prelude.js:1
    at Object.8../ScriptMap (marmite-src\js\scripts-front.js:3)
    at s (_prelude.js:1)
    at e (_prelude.js:1)
    at _prelude.js:1
    at _prelude.js:1
    at _prelude.js:1
3 @ marmite-src\js\_store.js:26
s @ _prelude.js:1
(anonymous) @ _prelude.js:1
8../ScriptMap @ marmite-src\js\scripts-front.js:3
s @ _prelude.js:1
e @ _prelude.js:1
(anonymous) @ _prelude.js:1
(anonymous) @ _prelude.js:1
(anonymous) @ _prelude.js:1
```

On firefox :

```
TypeError: $ is not a function[En savoir plus] scripts-front.js:351:11
        [3]< http://10.250.140.37/sites/all/themes/acti_main/tpl/js/scripts-front.js:351:11
        s http://10.250.140.37/sites/all/themes/acti_main/tpl/js/scripts-front.js:1:612
        s/< http://10.250.140.37/sites/all/themes/acti_main/tpl/js/scripts-front.js:1:671
        [8]< http://10.250.140.37/sites/all/themes/acti_main/tpl/js/scripts-front.js:859:14
        s http://10.250.140.37/sites/all/themes/acti_main/tpl/js/scripts-front.js:1:612
        e http://10.250.140.37/sites/all/themes/acti_main/tpl/js/scripts-front.js:1:791
        <anonyme> http://10.250.140.37/sites/all/themes/acti_main/tpl/js/scripts-front.js:1:377
        <anonyme> http://10.250.140.37/sites/all/themes/acti_main/tpl/js/scripts-front.js:1:316
        <anonyme> http://10.250.140.37/sites/all/themes/acti_main/tpl/js/scripts-front.js:1:2
```

I load `Jquery` before my script-front in the footer:

```
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/domready/ready.min.js?v=1.0.8"></script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=3.2.1"></script>
<script src="/core/assets/vendor/jquery-once/jquery.once.min.js?v=2.2.0"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/drupalSettingsLoader.js?v=8.5.4"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/drupal.js?v=8.5.4"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/drupal.init.js?v=8.5.4"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/progress.js?v=8.5.4"></script>
<script src="/core/misc/ajax.js?v=8.5.4"></script>
<script src="/sites/all/themes/acti_main/tpl/js/vendors.js?v=1.x"></script>
<script src="/sites/all/themes/acti_main/tpl/js/scripts-front.js?v=1.x"></script>
<script src="/sites/all/themes/acti_main/tpl/js/script-tech.js?v=1.x"></script>
```

I see that the scripts-front.js use Typescript, but I have never used Typescript. You can see the script here : /sites/all/themes/acti_main/tpl/js/scripts-front.js

The file begins :

```
(function(f){if(typeof exports==="object"&&typeof module!=="undefined"){module.exports=f()}else if(typeof define==="function"&&define.amd){define([],f)}else{var g;if(typeof window!=="undefined"){g=window}else if(typeof global!=="undefined"){g=global}else if(typeof self!=="undefined"){g=self}else{g=this}g.global = f()}})(function(){var define,module,exports;return (function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
```

I hope anyone may help me.

Comment: I don't see a `<script>` tag for `marmite-src\js\_store.js` in your footer markup.  Where is it?

Comment: What is `jquery.once.min.js`? Is that adding duplicate `$` to your window?

Comment: It does not use typescript its a js file. Typescript is a language which is compiled to javascript

Comment: Jonathan Wilson, I don't see this script too. This is the log of chrome.

Comment: Thanks  kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze, If is not Typescript, Is it node.js ??

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I replaced $ by JQuery in my js script-fronts.